# While loop to find which variables of list A occur in list B

Tags: python-3.x, list, while-loop

Probably because I'm a SUPER newbie, but I haven't found anything that quite matches what I'm looking for. I have two lists, and am searching for a While loop that will show many how many times each variable of list F shows up in list N. I'm having trouble even approaching this or framing it in my mind.

Here are my lists:

```
F = [4,7,2]
N = [2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4]
```

Basic framework given as hint:

```
    <set up index stuff>
     while ???:
        while ???:
            <if same, increment counter variable>
        print ?, "occurs in N", ?, "times"
```

I'm just totally lost - appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Yes, it does have to involve a loop for this particular exercise. OOPS on the variables - thanks! I'll fix it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heres a solution using the format you provided:

```
a = 0
while(a < len(F)):
  b = 0
  c = 0
  while(b < len(N)):
    if(F[a] == N[b]):
      c = c + 1
    b = b + 1
  print F[a], "occurs in N" , c , "times"
  a = a + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter

F = [4,7,2]
N = [2,3,4,2,5,6,3,2,6,7,3,4]

counts = Counter(N)
for item in F:
    print('{} occurs in N {} times'.format(item, counts[item]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d={}
for number in F:
    match=0
    for matching in N:
        if number==matching:
            match+=1 
            d[number]=match

print (d)
```

You could use the nested for loop above and the dictionary keys will correspond to the number and then the values of the dictionary corresponding to the number of times it matches